# Print each n-th row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, printing

is there an elegant solution to print only each n-th row of a pandas dataframe? for instance, I would like to only print each 2nd row.

this could be done via

```
i = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if ((i%2) == 0):
        print(row)
    i++
```

but is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

slice the df with a step param with `iloc`:

```
print(df.iloc[::2])

In [73]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[73]:
          a         b         c
0  0.613844 -0.167024 -1.287091
1  0.473858 -0.456157  0.037850
2  0.020583  0.368597 -0.147517
3  0.152791 -1.231226 -0.570839
4 -0.280074  0.806033 -1.610855

In [77]:
print(df.iloc[::2])

          a         b         c
0  0.613844 -0.167024 -1.287091
2  0.020583  0.368597 -0.147517
4 -0.280074  0.806033 -1.610855
```